# Out memory error

Tags: android

Hi i have been doing a project from school and when i ran my application i have the stack trace error shown below.

```
03-06 14:58:02.520 11265-11265/com.example.ray.cdmsv2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:873)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2970)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:147)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(TabLayout.java:1080)
                                                                            at com.example.ray.cdmsv2.Activities.CreateTaskActivity.onCreate(CreateTaskActivity.java:102)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

I have looked around for solution but i still cannot resolve the issue. My application is able to run smoothly on Samsung Galaxy A3. However when i tried to run my application on a S4 and Note 4 i receive the out of memory error. I have realized that when i implement some selector in my drawable which i call in my XML files, it will cause the error, however when i remove it the error does not occur anymore. Is there any explanation for this issue? Thank you very much for helping me out

Comment: You're perhaps not using memory effectively. Different devices have different specs, you should probably try to scale how much memory you use with respect to how much you actively have available.

Comment: Compress the size of the image you are using. So simple!!! Or prefer using vectors. Check materialdesignicons.com

Comment: check your image sizes and try to reduce the size as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

Delete the drawable and import it again using ImageAsset option.

The error is your image is too heavy for loading it into memory. Or better compress the image before copying it into the Drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by learning some best practices for memory usage by google at the dev docs @
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

If you're loading large bitmaps, its quite possible the available heap memory is not enough for your bitmaps.

Comment: FYI. This answer is now in the Low Quality queue; I guess it was flagged NAA by someone who mistook it for a link-only answer. I think it would be good to elaborate a little about memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is being choked by Android because it is using more memory than assigned, primarily due to a large image file being used as a drawable.

If it is an icon, use Android Studio's built in Image Asset generator to generate appropriate image sizes for each display type (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi and so on). If it is an image being loaded on an ImageView, you may try using the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library which will handle bitmap memory on its own.